# How to access a String-array for username authentification in an activity?

Tags: java, android, arrays, authentication

I want to create an android studio login page, using more than one account stored in the array list. how to verify that the username and password written are the same as the username and password stored in the arraylist

heres my array list in res :

```
<string-array name="user">
    <item>admin</item>
    <item>jhon</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="pass">
    <item>admin</item>
    <item>littlejhon</item>
</string-array>
```

here my activity code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;    
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

public class PassActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    CardView card;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pass);

        final String[] use = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.user);
        final String[] pas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pass);

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        card     = findViewById(R.id.card);

        card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Objects.equals(username.getText().toString(), use)
                    &&
                    Objects.equals(password.getText().toString(),pas))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        PassActivity.this,
                        "You have Authenticated Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        PassActivity.this,
                        "Authentication Failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

thank for helping me, Hopefully, someone has some experience in this. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for each pair in arrays:

```java
 public void onClick(View view) {
    boolean found = false;
    String myUsername = username.getText().toString();
    String myPassword = password.getText().toString();

    for (int i = 0; i < use.length; i++) {
      if (use[i].equals(myUsername) && pas[i].equals(myPassword)) {
             Toast.makeText(PassActivity.this,"You have Authenticated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           found = true;
           break;
      }
     }

     if (!found) {
          Toast.makeText(PassActivity.this,"Authentication Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] usernames = getStringArray(R.array.usernames);
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String candidate = editText.getText().toString();
boolean submit_authenticate = isAuthenticated(candidate, usernames);

if(submit_authenticate){
    Toast.makeText(PassActivity.this,"You have Authenticated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(PassActivity.this,"Authentication Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public boolean isAuthenticated(String candidate, String[] usernames) {
   for(String username : usernames) {
      if(candidate.equals(username)) {
        return true;
      } 
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

  final String[] UserArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.user);
  final String[] passArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pas);

  String Username = username.getText().toString();
  String Password = password.getText().toString();

  if (Arrays.asList(UserArray).contains(Username) && Arrays.asList(passArray).contains(Password )) {
    // authenticate successfully
  }else{
     // authentication failed
   }

}
```